# Does putting multiple posts into the same blog categories cause duplicate content issues?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, categories

In our latest project we have added a blog which has an url of `http://www.example.be/tips-en-advies/`. Then we have some categories which have an url of `http://www.example.be/tips-en-advies/categorie-1/`, `http://www.example.be/tips-en-advies/categorie-2/`, ...

We have now added 2 posts which both are of `categorie-1`.

If we go to the `http://www.example.be/tips-en-advies/` page we see these 2 posts and if we go to the `http://www.example.be/tips-en-advies/categorie-1/` page we see the same 2 posts.

Is this duplicate content or not? If so then I could add a new post of another categorie so that on the page `http://www.example.be/tips-en-advies/` we see 3 posts.

Comment: Of course it is duplicate if you see the same things on the pages.   But do you need to prevent that?  No.   Google will just not index one of the duplicate pages.   See: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: If your categories and tags are not well formatted (in terms of quality of webpage and duplicate content), then you should use no-index tag on those pages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this will be viewed as duplicate content. However, Google will not 'penalise' you as such. It will just rank one of the pages above the other. If you have a preference for which page you want to rank, you can add a rel=canonical tag on the page that you do not wish to rank.